# How to predict a flight distance?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, forces, home-experiment, elasticity

I conducted an experiment by varying the stretch length of a rubber band (angle is always constant) which resulted in different flight distance. My teacher told me to find an equation/law to explain how a given stretch length can make the rubber band fly a particular distance (this is an independent research), but I still am stuck. Please help me out. Thank you in advance!